java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: Error inflating class fragment
The error I'm encountering when I start my app, after splash screen, it crashes with this error in logcat:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.tapz.app, PID: 27735
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tapz.app/com.tapz.app.ui.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.tapz.app:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #21 in com.tapz.app:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class fragment

My HomeActivity.kt class is:
package com.tapz.app.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
import com.tapz.app.R
import com.tapz.app.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_home)


        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_home)
                    true
                }

                R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_dashboard)
                    true
                }

                R.id.navigation_settings -> {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_settings)
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
    }
}

And my home_activity.xml is:
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container">

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_home"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chip_nav_item_bg"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                app:itemRippleColor="@null"
                app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@drawable/menu_item_background"
                app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationTextStyle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:elevation="@dimen/_1sdp"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

I have this activity called HomeActivity which hosts 3 fragments, on one of these fragments there's a button that leads to activity. I am using MVVM and Hilt here for the API calls, in that activity getting called by fragment, APIs are called in that activity.

Please check your XML file as there is some issue with that.

Check whether you implement Hilt properly, that may also cause this issue. Check you declare the application class in the manifest and application class with @hiltAndroidApp
